# Replacing the character \n by an actual linebreak on text

Tags: bash, unix, sed

So, I have a text file that looks like that:

```
this text \n and more text.
```

I am trying to replace the characters \n by a real linebreak and for that I am trying something like this:

```
sed 's/\n/\n/g' inputfile
```

Any ideas on how to use sed to do this ? Thank you.

Comment: Here you find it <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140763/replace-n-by-a-newline-in-sed-portably>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bodo's answer works on Linux (with GNU `sed`). But on systems with BSD `sed`, e.g. MacOS, `\n` in the replacement string isn't replaced with a newline, so you need to put a literal newline into the replacement. And it needs to be escaped, otherwise you get the error "unescaped newline inside substitute pattern".

```
sed $'s/\\\\n/\\\n/g'
```

`$'...'` tells `bash` to replace C-style escape sequences in the string. So you need to double all the backslashes to get them literally into the string.

Comment: This `sed`  works but will need `bash` and may not work on something like `dash`. I suggested a POSIX compliant `sed` command that will work on OSX bash, dash, ksh, zsh

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the backslash in the search pattern

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\n/, "\n")} 1' file
```

Note that awk solution works with POSIX awk as well gnu-awk.

Here is a POSIX sed solution:

```
sed 's/\\n/\
/g' file
```